# Getting very weird error while using angular/cli version 1.0.0-beta.28.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-cli

Sends this error when trying to ng serve the application

> 86% hashingcrypto.js:74   this._handle.update(data, encoding);
>                  ^ TypeError: Data must be a string or a buffer
>       at TypeError (native)
>       at Hash.update (crypto.js:74:16)
>       at HarmonyExportImportedSpecifierDependency.updateHash 
>       (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-  src\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyExportImportedSpecifierDependency.js:144:8)
>       at C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\DependenciesBlock.js:33:5
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at NormalModule.DependenciesBlock.updateHash (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\DependenciesBlock.js:32:20)
>       at NormalModule.Module.updateHash (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Module.js:162:41)
>       at NormalModule.updateHash (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:327:30)
>       at modules.forEach.m (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:253:31)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Chunk.updateHash (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:253:16)
>       at Compilation.createHash (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1121:10)
>       at sealPart2 (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:605:9)
>       at next (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:138:11)
>       at Compilation. (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:110:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\seanr\projects\DerrickAlphaFebTest\angular-src\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:140:14)

Comment: It's very hard to debug such a problem. There are many dependencies with libraries and also node version (which is what?). The best approach is to remove things one by one until it stops breaking; or, work the other way around, by starting a new app, then adding things one by one until it stops working. The first thing to try is upgrading angular-cli to 1.0.0.

Comment: might be related to this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4072 ? please see comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I just started a new project and copied over the package.json and node_modules and that fixed everything.

Comment: Its depends of @ngtools/webpack version wich angular choose to install on its node_modules folder.

I had its same issue in an Angular project and i added on devDependencies the package "":"1.4.0". (we have increased the version wich angular choose to install as his dependency) and this generic erros gone away and the project import/exports erros was shown

Answer (score 3):

You can improve the error message by manually editing the following file: node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyExportImportedSpecifierDependency.js and insert some log at line 144:

```
     updateHash(hash) {
      super.updateHash(hash);
      const hashValue = this.getHashValue(this.importDependency.module);
      if (this.importDependency.module != null){
         // console.log('Module resource: ',       this.importDependency.module.resource);
      }else{
         console.log('\nFile not found: ', this.importDependency);
      }
      hash.update(hashValue);
   }
```

then you can get clear error message

```
86% hashing                                  
File not found:  HarmonyImportDependency {
module: null,
request: '@angular/cdk/a11y',
userRequest: '@angular/cdk/a11y',
range: [ 237, 339 ],
importedVar: '__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_cdk_a11y__',
loc: 
SourceLocation {
 start: Position { line: 9, column: 0 },
 end: Position { line: 9, column: 102 } } }
crypto.js:97
this._handle.update(data, encoding);
```

then search for the file specified in **request**, here it is **@angular/cdk/a11y**

in my case i found that,the file named @angular/cdk/a11y was missing. I installed the missing file to get it working

Reference:[Thanks to toub's answer in github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4072)